# Search for a string in a line and append related lines

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file containing some `ID` (identifier) and `DS` (description) lines. I'd like to keep the rows containing the `string` value in their `ID` line, as well as all the following (related) `DS` lines before the following `ID` . For exemple:

```
ID  number1 string
DS  item11
DS  item12
ID  number2 not_string
DS  item21 
DS  item22
ID  number3 string
DS  item31
DS  item32
```

Will return:

```
ID  number1 string
DS  item11
DS  item12
ID  number3 string
DS  item31
DS  item32
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right, I change the `not_string` in your input for test:

```
ID  number1 string                                                              
DS  item11                                                                      
DS  item12                                                                      
ID  number2 qwerty                                                               
DS  item21                                                                      
DS  item22                                                                      
ID  number3 string                                                              
DS  item31                                                                      
DS  item32
```

Try:

```
$ awk '/ID/ && !/string/{flag=0;next};/string/{flag=1};flag' file 
ID  number1 string
DS  item11
DS  item12
ID  number3 string
DS  item31
DS  item32
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '/ID.* s/p;//,/ID/{//!p;}' <<\DATA                              
    ID  number1 string
    DS  item11
    DS  item12
    ID  number2 not_string
    DS  item21
    DS  item22
    ID  number3 string
    DS  item31
    DS  item32
DATA
```

That relies on this [POSIX defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html) behavior for `sed` regex addresses:

> If an RE is empty *(that is, no pattern is specified)* `sed` shall behave as if the last RE used in the last command applied *(either as an `/address/` or as part of a `s/ubsti/tute/` command)* was specified.

When the top of your search is matched by the `/ID.* s/` address it is then  `p`rinted. A line range is specified between the lines matching the last address `//,/ID/` and the next *ID* line. Any lines falling `{within;}` that range *(or an incomplete one if it ends with the last line)* that do `!not` match `//` are also `p`rinted.

All that comes through are the `/ID.* s/` lines I explicitly `p`rint and all lines occuring *between* that and the next occurring `/ID/` line - or *(and including)* the last line, whichever comes first.

#### OUTPUT

```
ID  number1 string
DS  item11
DS  item12
ID  number3 string
DS  item31
DS  item32
```