# Indirection on a Bash array

Tags: bash, array

Is there a possibility to write the following script without the loop?

```
IPv4_first=1.1.1.1
IPv4_second=2.2.2.2
IPv4_third=3.3.3.3

IPv4_all=() 

for var in ${!IPv4_@}
do
   IPv4_all+=(${!var})
done

printf "'%s'\n" "${IPv4_all[@]}"
```

Something like:

```
IPv4_all=${!${!IPv4_@}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be the ugliest Bash code I've ever written, but...

```
IPv4_first=1.1.1.1
IPv4_second=2.2.2.2
IPv4_third=3.3.3.3

names=(${!IPv4_@})
eval "IPv4_all=(${names[@]/#/$})"
printf "'%s'\n" "${IPv4_all[@]}"
```

Look Ma, no loop!

[`${names[@]/#/$}` prepends](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `$` to the start of every element of the array, by matching an empty string anchored to the start of each element. That gives an array of variable dereferences, which we can expand inside `eval` to get the variable references inside the array initialiser. These need to be two separate lines because you can't apply multiple parameter expansions at the same time.

The output is:

```
'1.1.1.1'
'2.2.2.2'
'3.3.3.3'
```

as expected.

It's possible to replace the line with:

```
IPv4_all=($(eval "echo ${names[@]/#/$}"))
```

rather than `eval`ling the array assignment. I'm not sure whether that's any better or not.

If your variable values might contain spaces or other IFS characters, you can change the eval:

```
eval "IPv4_all=($(printf '"$%s" ' "${names[@]}"))"
```

That properly double-quotes all the variable dereferences.

Comment: That assumes variable names or values don't contain IFS or wildcard characters.

Comment: I've edited in cover for the values with `printf`. If your variable names contain IFS characters I question your judgement, but you can modify the code accordingly.

Comment: IFS may have been modified beforehand (and contain underscore or digits or letters...). It's my policy to set IFS whenever I use the split+glob operator.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, I think, though I'll accept that I could be missing some fundamental point:

```
IPv4_first=1.1.1.1
IPv4_second=2.2.2.2
IPv4_third=3.3.3.3

IPv4_all=( $(set | sed '/IPv4_.*[=)]/!d;s///') )

printf "'%s'\n" "${IPv4_all[@]}"
```

#### OUTPUT

```
'1.1.1.1'
'2.2.2.2'
'3.3.3.3'
```

This is better:

```
eval IPv4_all=( "$(set |
    grep -E '^IPv4_[_[:alnum:]]*=([^(]|$)' |
    sed 's/\([^=]*\).*/${\1+"$\1"} /')"
)
```

`grep` only gets safe lines that match your target var. `sed` surrounds them in parameter expansion tokens so they evaluate away to nothing if they're not actually current shell variable names.

Comment: That assumes the variable values are not multi-line and that you don't have variables whose value contains `\nIPv4_...=` or whose name contains (and doesn't start with) `IPv4_`.

Comment: Yeah - I just realized that - I have to evaluate them away - return only var names. I'm about to do that now.

Comment: @mikeserv: I can see what the `s///` part is doing but I don't understand why... Can you explain it?

Comment: Umm... Actually, as it happens, I am, at the moment, very well disposed to do so, yes. I just answered a question about that: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146509/52934

Comment: A slightly more concise and legible idiom for `sed '/.../!d;s///'` is `sed -n 's/...//p'`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - it was screwed anyway - the `=(` types - it's hard to choose them concisely. I `grep`ped it. Pretty sure it's solid now. But you do have a point - I usually choose to `-n` when it will shorten the over all statement.

Comment: Note that `grep 'a\|b'` is not standard/portable. `grep -E 'a|b'` is.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks again very much - it's cleaner that way anyway. By the way - the `-n` is actually exactly what I did at the link I pointed Ray to.

Answer (score 1):

My competition entry on the ugliest/most convoluted bash code ;-):

```
eval 'declare(){ v=${2%%=*};[[ $v = IPv4_* ]]&&IPv4_all+=("${!v}");};'"$(declare -p)"
unset -f declare
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `IPv4_all` variable:

```
eval printf "\'%s\'\\\n" $(printf "$%s\n" ${!IPv4_@})
```

Output:

```
'1.1.1.1'
'2.2.2.2'
'3.3.3.3'
```