# egrep -rnw . -e "string" returns line and adjacent lines

Tags: bash, grep

I use,

```
egrep -rnw . -e "string"
```

a lot (in bash), but it would be nice to add some context to the returned results. This would be the line before and after it. Maybe the two lines before and afer it.

Is this difficult to do?

grep, egrep, pcregrep, etc. does not matter.

Thanks

PS. I just saw this: [Search for a string in a line and append related lines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146493/search-for-a-string-in-a-line-and-append-related-lines) which I didn't think of searching for "append".

Comment: Have you looked at the `-A` and `-B` options?

Comment: I saw that but I was thinking those lines still had to have "string" in them. I guess I was misunderstanding.

Comment: Or `-Cn`, which is the same as `-An -Bn` for _n_ lines.  The mnemonic I use is After/Before/Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many `grep` implementations have `-A n`, `-B n` and `-C n` (where `-C n` is equivalent to `-A n -B n`).

The `n` above is the number of lines of context that you would like to have for each matching line.  `-A` would give you context above the match, `-B` below, and `-C` around on both sides.

These options are extensions to [the standard description of the `grep` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/grep.html).